# How to iterate over object values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like this:

```
{
  username: {
    hobby: [
      {
        hobby1: "cricket",
        hobby2: "swim"
      },
      {
        hobby3: "dance",
        hobby4: "zumba"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can easily do a `forEach` and do `console.log(item)` but what if I just want the values cricket,swim,dance,zumba alone (don’t need `hobby1` through `hobby4`). Can someone show me how to extract the values alone?

Comment: The question is not clear. Where is `hobbies` in the object?

Comment: Can you show us for the exact output details?

Comment: what value output you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily loop through the objects and arrays using a `for` within a `for` like this:

```js
let obj = {
      username: {
          hobby: [
              {
                  hobby1: "cricket",
                  hobby2: "swim"
              },
              {
                  hobby3: "dance",
                  hobby4: "zumba"
              }
          ]
     }
}

for(let hobbies of obj.username.hobby) {
    for(let hobby in hobbies) {
          console.log(hobbies[hobby])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an object with just the hobbies, you can reduce the array to return that

```js
var obj = {
  username: {
    hobby: [{
        hobby1: "cricket",
        hobby2: "swim"
      },
      {
        hobby3: "dance",
        hobby4: "zumba"
      }
    ]
  }
}

var obj2 = obj.username.hobby.reduce((a, b) => {
  Object.entries(b).forEach(x => a[x[0]] = x[1]); return a;
}, {})

console.log(obj2);
console.log(Object.values(obj2)); // just the values
```

Comment: Syntax error. Can resolve it?

Comment: @RameshRajendran - then get a proper browser

Comment: IE 11 is not a proper browser?

Comment: No, it's not, it doesn't support `Object.entries` or arrow functions

Comment: Then how can we accept it is a good answer to OP, if the OP using this same browser?

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't use ES6 in my answers, because you're using an outdated browser ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran This is ES6 syntax which has been the officially released standard for two years. You should know that this is ES6, you should know that your browser can’t keep up with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, what i understand is that you just need "hobbies" as value not they indexes

```
var json= {
        username: {
           hobby: [{
               hobby1: "cricket",
               hobby2: "swim"
           },
           {
               hobby3: "dance",
               hobby4: "zumba"
           }]
         }
       }    ;

var hobbies=json.username.hobby;

var hobbies_arr=[];
var i=0;
for(var item in hobbies){
     item=hobbies[item];          
     for(var hobby in item){
         hobby=item[hobby];
         hobbies_arr[i]=hobby;
         i++;
     }
}

console.log(hobbies_arr);
```

Out put would be

Array [ "cricket", "swim", "dance", "zumba" ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate all your hobbies in an array.

```js
var obj = {username: {hobby: [{hobby1: "cricket",hobby2: "swim"},{hobby3: "dance",hobby4: "zumba"}]}};

var result = obj.username.hobby.reduce((res, obj) => res.concat(Object.values(obj)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```